# MySQL 8.0 - Could not acquire management access - Administration issue

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, mysql-8.0, mysqladmin

I am using MySQL Workbench for many months, it was working fine. Today, when I tried to open Server Status in the MANAGEMENT tab, below error occurred.

[image]

MYSQL80 and Windows Management Instrumentation services are running.

I saw some posts regarding this issue, but the solution they have given was for older version.

Everything works fine. Even Test Connection is successful. But I am not able to access management related activities even though I am using "root" user.

How to resolve this issue? If it's administration access issue, how to check and change administration access privilege's?